# "Don't count on it"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What's the best way to say "Don't count on it" to somebody in German when they have high hopes on something that is more likely not to happen than to happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here a collection:

> Verlass dich (lieber) nicht drauf.
>
> Geh (lieber) nicht zu fest davon aus.
>
> Wart's erst mal ab.
>
> Das bleibt abzuwarten.
>
> Ich wär' mir da an deiner Stelle nicht zu sicher.

All those are applicable if you are talking about a third party dependent hope and they have a very skeptical if not negative tone.

Comment: "nicht auf sie verlassen" means don't rely on them/it.

Answer (score 6):

> Da würd' ich nicht drauf wetten

is one possibility (*würd'* is a colloquial shortening of *würde*). Literally: I wouldn't bet on it [if I were you].

Comment: Wieso gibt es für so eine 30-Sekunden-Antwort 4 Upvotes und für andere, in die ich das Hundertfache oder mehr an Zeit stecke, nur 3, 2, 1 oder gar 0 Votes?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: In der Kürze liegt die Würze.

Answer (score 2):

Mit

> Zähl nicht drauf!

gibt es den gleichen Ausdruck auch auf Deutsch.

Das ist aber leicht zu finden, etwa [hier bei dict.leo](http://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&search=count%20on%20something): zählen, rechnen, bauen, verlassen.

Comment: Danke! Du hast recht , dass mit dem zählen und rechnen ist auch leicht zu finden aber ich war mich da nicht sicher ob das umgangsprächlich auch so verwendet wird oder dass es bessere Alternativen gibt.

Comment: Can't really confirm this as common usage. The "don't bet on it" variant seems to be far more widespread, though this may be a regional thing.

Comment: @Alan: Woher kommt die Anforderung den häufigst verwendeten Ausdruck finden zu wollen? Ist denn `Don't count on it` der häufigste Ausdruck? Du selbst greifst sogar zu `Don't bet on it`, wo doch ein deutscher Ausdruck gesucht ist. :)

Comment: @Jonhy: In welcher Hinsicht soll die Alternative besser sein? Meinst Du, dict.leo denkt sich Formulierungen aus, die es gar nicht gibt? Dann kann man das mit einer Googlesuche überprüfen.

Comment: @ user unknown. Ich habe nicht gesagt dass dict.leo sich nur Quatsch ausdenkt. Jedoch wäre es nicht das erste Mal dass man manche Dinge umgangsprächlich eher anders sagen würde als wie es in einem Wörterbuch steht. Deswegen frage ich es hier einfach mal, das ist doch nicht so schlimm?

Comment: @ user unknown "Don't bet on it" ist die freie Übersetzung der Antwort von @eugene-seidel -- und ja, ich bin mir der Absurdität eine idiomatische Übersetzung wörtlich zurückzuübersetzen durchaus bewusst ;) Dass die gängig(st)e Übersetzung gesucht wird ist impliziert: da kein engerer Kontext gegeben ist, sollte die Übersetzung so allgemeingültig (und -verständlich) sein, wie möglich.

Comment: @pluma: `Die gängige` Übersetzung unterstellt gegen jede Erfahrung, dass nur eine Übersetzung gängig ist. `Die gängigste` dass Du Zugang zu Häufigkeitstabellen o.ä. hast und dass über Frage wie zu zählen ist Konsens besteht. Die Frage richtet sich auch ganz eindeutig auf die Qualität, nicht die Quantität. Das geht nicht nur in der Sprache meist auseinander.

Answer (score 2):

> Dafür würd ich nicht meine Hand ins Feuer legen!